# Looking for an explanation of OpenDatabase()

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am new to the VBA. I am given a problem to display a proper message whenever user enter wrong username and password. Currently we receive below error message and users get confused with this.

> frmDBConnect:errorHandlerErr.Description=ODBC--connection to 'DB2T-XX'
>   Failed.

Please see my code. What is happening is whenever I enter a wrong username or password db becomes nothing (db=nothing) but whenever there is a valid username and password db has data and I am able to login to next screen

What I am guessing is db should only become nothing when provided database does not exist not when username and password is wrong.

Any help here will be appreciated.

```
lConnect = "ODBC;DSN=" & sDB2SubSystem & ";UID=" & UID & ";PWD=" & PWD & ";SERVER=" & sDB2SubSystem
Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Set db = ws.OpenDatabase("", False, True, lConnect)
```

Comment: You just need to test for that specific error in the error handler.  From the 3 lines of code provided (with the error handling missing), it's going to be hard to be more specific than that.

Comment: I'm not sure what your exact question is here, but I can say that the object `db` will be `Nothing` if the attempt to initialize that object (here by using `ws.OpenDatabase()`) fails since the [`OpenDatabase()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/workspace-opendatabase-method-dao) of your `ws` "Workspace" object returns a "Database" object. If it fails, it can't return a "Database" object and so it can't set `db` to anything.

Comment: As for catching that specific error, you need an [On Error statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement) wherein you can redirect the codepath to a [Label](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/how-to-label-statements) wherein you can see what `Err` was returned and act on it. Read up on that first link to see how to do all that.

Comment: What does this have to do with mainframes?

Comment: In the connection string we see ODBC = DB2T. Try google. DB2 is a wide used IBM mainframe database.